# select all from first table and add rows of specific column with a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have two tables:

1. `product_session`
2. `product_sale`

`product_session` and `product_sale` map with `product_session_id`, which is primary key for `product_session` and foreign for `product_sale`.

`product_sale` can return multiple row against `product_session_id`.

`product_sale` has 4 column:

- `product_sale_id`
- `product_session_id`
- `sales1`
- `sales2`.

Now I need a query which will return all columns of first table (`product_session`) against `product_session_id` and `sum(sales1),sum(sales2)` of second table(`product_sale`),if `product_sale` has multiple row against `product_session_id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   product_session.*, SUM(product_sale.sales1), SUM(product_sale.sales2)
FROM     product_session LEFT JOIN product_sale USING (product_session_id)
GROUP BY product_session_id
```

Comment: what will the query return if product_sale has only one row against product_session_id,giving some weird result

Comment: @mayankbaluni: Then it will return the sum of that one value, which will be that value itself.